# What to report in the build model, asses model and evaluate results steps of CRISP-DM?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know what to report in the following steps of CRISP-DM?

- **Build Model**: what should be reported for parameter settings, models and model description? I used grid search to tune hyperparameters.
- **Assess Model**: what should be reported for model assessment and revised parameter settings?
- **Evaluate Results**: what should be reported for assessment of data mining results?

[image]

In fact, I used just Logistic regression to do a classification task using a procedure like what is depicted below:
[image]

Could the final model evaluation on test data set be considered as a part of Evaluate Results or it should be done on new data?

Comment: hi, I've been busy these days and couldn't respond to your comment. I don't know whether you've solved it or not. I noticed you have deleted your comment. Have you solved it?

Comment: @Media Hi Thanks a lot. Your welcome. I was in doubt about my solution so, I posted it in the second and third comment of the answer provided to this post. Still I am not sure about it.

Comment: I guess it highly depends on your task. for classification tasks reporting the accuracy is customary but for regression tasks, I've even seen plotting learning-curve-like graphs too.

Comment: @Media Hi. I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know whether model selection:




1-  just refers to algorithm selection i.e., finding the best predictive algorithm e.g., SVC vs Logistic Regression? or

2- it could interchangeably used with hyperparameter tuning of  a given learning algorithm e.g., SVC?




Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: Hi, Basically I guess the latter is more correct due to the fact that when ever you try to find an appropriate algorith, you will attempt to set and tune the hyper parameters.

Comment: @Media Hi could you please let me know if it is right to do  the following revision? parameter settings: hyperparameter tuning via grid search , models: the coefficients of the best tuned logistic regression , model description: explanation of the coefficients, model assessment: the results (confusion matrix) of whole training data set, revised parameter settings: nothing is needed and assessment of data mining : the results (confusion matrix) of test data set. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi I guess I know the answer. Remind me tommorow to respond. I have cold and headache right now.

Comment: @Media I hope you feel better soon.

Comment: Thanks! parameter setting: it may have different meannings and one of them can be what you've referred but consider that grid search is not the only way to find the hyperparameters; there are different approaches. Models: they can be any valid model that takes the input and maps it to output, it is not necessarily the best one. model description: actually by model description I don't know what you want to say but consider the fact that in ML some algorithms are well descriptive like decision trees that you can see the rules and they are meaningful for humans but neural nets are not descriptive

Comment: Due to the fact that those weights do not have any touchable meaning. Model assessment: there are numerous techiniques for evaluating different models which depends on the task; confusion matrices are one of them.It highly depends on your data and your environment to decide which one to use. You should consider that in machine learning the training accuracy is just the start point and is not really important. Your test accuracy shows your real learning. About the rest, I don't have experience.

Comment: @Media Special thanks to you. Sorry, do you know a book which describes the data science process as provided here: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/03/data-science-process-rediscovered.html

Comment: In coursera there is a specialization data science in python. They have introduced some which all are available.

Comment: Actually I don't know.

Comment: kari nakardam :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the second link does not work but consider this point. Machine learning is a really big field and those who try to classify it into different subparts are just attempting to introduce the field to newbies. I prefer not to classify SVMs as neural networks. They are completely different, They have a closed form for the solution. Neural nets are different at least based on what I've experienced.

Comment: I don't know why. I have not been able to download even the first link till now.

Comment: Sorry for seeing late, I've been busy so much these days.

Comment: sorry my late response.

Comment: @Media sorry could you please answer this question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37220/how-to-compute-g-mean-score thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The way you are trying to present the outcome is pretty good.

I cannot say that the following procedure is the standard procedure in my scenario I did something like this:
[image: CRISP-DM]

This is how I presented to my managers to make them understand the procedure which I followed.

I made a slide for each and every segment and highlighted the points which are necessary for them to be known.

While showing the results, I named the data(accuracies) differently

1. Train Set Accuracy: Which is 70% of the total dataset, derive the accuracy % also called model accuracy
2. Test Set Accuracy: Test set which is 30% of the total dataset, derive the accuracy called Test Accuracy
3. Blind Test Accuracy: Which is completely new data, here I trained the model with whole dataset and then tested using the new data(you can also call it as Validation set)

This is how I presented:
[image: Accuracy Table]

Since yours is also a classification problem to explain it better I gave them the breakdown:

[image: Further Breakdown of Accuracies]

Do let me know if you have any issues, would love to help you.

Comment: yeah true, the about is clear right? Do you think anything else needs to be appended?

Comment: I first divide the whole dataset into training and test data set. The training set will be used to tune hyperparameters via k-fold cross-validation. Then, the whole training data set is trained using the best determined parameters in the previous step. Finally, the model is tested on the test data set. So, I decided to report:

Comment: parameter settings: hyperparameter tuning via grid search ,  models: the results (confusion matrix) of whole training data set, model description: the coefficients of logistic regression, model assessment: the learning curve,  revised parameter settings:nothing is needed  and assessment of data mining :  the results (confusion matrix) of test data set. @Toros91

Comment: This would go in the report right?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking of doing so. Is it right?

Comment: yeah it is absolutely fine, if you share all such results, it would be great for the next person to understand better

Comment: Sure will try to do that and share it with you.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for this inconvenience. Could you please let me know the class-weight in the sklearn's classifiers e.g., logistic regression is classified into which category? @Toros91

Comment: I dint understand what you meant in that, why would a ml algorithm me classified into one of the sampling techniques?

Comment: In fact, it is possible to use class-weight to handle imbalanced classes for example, https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/logistic_regression/handling_imbalanced_classes_in_logistic_regression/ However, I don't know how this strategy could be classified in one of those categorization for dealing with imbalanced classes. @Toros91

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78996/discussion-between-toros91-and-ebrahimi).

Comment: Could you please let me know how to draw the database shape in the middle of CRISP-DM, which you named it "data", using Microsoft word or visio 2016? Thanks in advance @Toros91

Comment: you directly look for a database png and place it in the center of the diagram and merge those both. unless you want to develop it all by yourself