# How to compute G-mean score?

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, class-imbalance, metric

I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know how to fix the following issue:

I used [sklearn.metrics.fowlkes_mallows_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.fowlkes_mallows_score.html) to compute G-mean score for my binary classification problem, but it produces `nan`:

```
AUC: 0.960674 
Accuracy: 0.949137 
Cohen Kappa: 0.484456 
F_measure: 0.508772 
G-mean: 0.833217 
G-mean1: nan 
Matthews: CorrCoef 0.510088 
Precision: 0.391892 
Recall: 0.725
```

However, it should be: `0.533031`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to put your data?

Comment: @Media sorry, I can not put my data because it is not too small. However, this issue is also reported here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8101 but I couldn't understand how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to update it?

Comment: @Media sorry I installed the latest version of scikit using anaconda. However, unfortunately the problem is not solved.

Comment: I guess the issue may still be remained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from imblearn.metrics import geometric_mean_score
```

Docs are [here](http://glemaitre.github.io/imbalanced-learn/generated/imblearn.metrics.geometric_mean_score.html).

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that `fowlkes_mallows_score` is designed to evaluate clustering and you are trying to apply it to evaluate binary classification.

Comment: Thanks, could you please let me know how to compute G-mean score for binary classification?